# ISP says IPv6 will solve network congestion issues?

Tags: networking, router, internet, ipv6

I recently moved, and fiber installation was very delayed in my area (South Japan) due to a major overhaul with the national telecommunications company.

In the meantime I got cable internet. Its pretty alright. Reliable. Not insanely fast, but it will do the job. And it does it at the same speed every time. Consistently 50-75 Mbps over 2.4Ghz.

I finally got my fiber installation last week. Though during the day my speeds over 5GHz vary between 100Mbps and 200Mbps, over 2.4GHz 50-100, which is good. At night the rate is abysmal. Down under 5Mbps, sometimes less than 1Mbps. This is the speed measurement from the router directly. Same equipment in both networks. Cat 6 ethernet cable, same Netgear Nighthawk R7000 router.

I tried to suggest that this is much slowdown for just congestion, but maybe I'm wrong. The technician with the ISP seems convinced that this much slow down is due to network congestion in the evenings, and says that an IPv6 upgrade will solve the problem.

Can anyone help me understand this? I'm a software engineer by trade, so I'm a bit lost when it comes to networking. I would have assumed NAT would have solved any issue up to my house, but perhaps the IPv6 main lines here are just bigger than the IPv4 main lines.

Some of the discussion between me and the networking guy is lost in translation, and its not his job to explain how networks work anyway.

Comment: By "fiber" do you mean fiber all way to the house, or just FTTC where the last part still goes through copper DSL or something such?

Comment: No, IPv6 WILL not solve a problem of congested links. It MAY help with overloaded NAT equipment (as it doesn't require it) but I wouldn't be surprised if they exchanged NAT for NAT64 as most Internet sites are still on IPv4. So, I am not buying this explanation.

Comment: @user1686 FTTH. Fiber all the way to the modem in my house.

Comment: @Tomek that’s what I thought. I mentioned NAT, and he said something like “yes. Very good.” Japanese is a vague and indirect language so I took that to mean that maybe NAT problems were the issue but I don’t know enough about it for that to make sense to me right away. I’ll try it. I fully expect that it will not solve anything and I will cancel the service and go back to Cable, since at least that one is consistent.

Comment: Actually IPv6 can help to avoid the congestion that is common in Japan at night, by ensuring stable data transmission with minimal delay. I wouldn't dismiss the advice of that technician out of hand.

Comment: ‘@harrymc. Thanks for the input! Is it because of not having to use NAT at all?

Comment: NAT is no that simple. You don't need NAT when the full path between you and the service (including it) is IPv6. If the service is IPv4 only (which often is the case) you will likely get some NAT in between - be it regular IPv4 port and address translation or NAT64 if your end is IPv6 only.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 can indeed solve this issue, and in practice, has. Daytime transmission is often over 200Mbps, and evening, congested time transmission exceeds 40 Mbps. Comparatively on IPv4, 50-80Mbps was common during the day, and 1-4Mbps was in the evening.

Why? I have no idea. But I wanted to put an answer here to say that apparently it can, and I think it makes sense.

Since there is such a congestion of IP addresses in the IPv4 range, especially when mixed with the evening traffic volume, and constant renewing and requesting of new leases of IP addresses. Stacking NAT on NAT on NAT can cause stability issues with an ever changing array of congestions. IPv6 resolves that stability inconsistency.